# Python sockets -- client not receiving UDP datagram

Tags: python, sockets, udp

**Server code:**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # server UDP socket
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1) # bypass OS lock on port
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 9999)) # bind socket to host and port 9999
while True:
    message, ip = s.recvfrom(1024) # receive data passed through socket
    print "Server:\n\tMessage \"{}\" received...\n\tIt has a length of {}".format(
            message, len(message))
    s.sendto(str(len(message)), (socket.gethostname(), 9999)) # send message length in bytes back to client
    s.close() # close UDP connection with client
    sys.exit(0) # terminate server process
```

**Client code:**

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))
message = "Pointless text."
print "Client:\n\tSending message \"{}\" to the server...\n\tIt has a length of {}".format(
        message, len(message))
s.sendto(message, (socket.gethostname(), 9999))
while True:
    response, ip = s.recvfrom(1024)
    if int(response) == len(message):
        print "Client:\n\tThe server returned count {} which is equal to the client's count of {}.".format(response, len(message))
    else:
        print "Client:\n\tThe server returned count {} which is not equal to the client's count of {}.".format(response, len(message))
s.close()
```

**Output:**

```
Running client in UDP mode...
Running server in UDP mode...

Client:
    Sending message "Pointless text." to the server...
    It has a length of 15
Server:
    Message "Pointless text." received...
    It has a length of 15
```

The client side `recvfrom` never gets triggered and I can't figure out why.

Here are the complete [client](https://pastebin.com/sGbLNnkd) and [server](https://pastebin.com/qeP8K8aT) files if you want to test them directly on your machine like so:

```
python2.7 server udp & python2.7 client udp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your server code, you are sending the result to the server's address (`9999`), not the client's (`ip`).

Try this:

```
s.sendto(str(len(message)), ip) # send message length in bytes back to client
```

Comment: Thank you sir. I assumed the client code `s.connect((socket.gethostname(), 9999))` would configure the client socket to receive on port 9999 and the client code `s.sendto(message, (socket.gethostname(), 9999))` would configure the socket to send to port 9999...can you illuminate why the address in `connect()` is necessary if it doesn't configure the receiving port and the` sendto()` handles the destination port?

Comment: Actually, I just answered my own question -- removing the `connect()` line doesn't affect my program.